# Living room fan

Tags: electrical

I have a ceiling fan in my living room my son broke the chain and the fan ran for a few weeks till I got around to trying to fix it.

I replaced the 4 wire switch. Now the fan wont even come on, the light works but not the fan.

I took the fan and light switch to a fan store, they checked it out and said the capacitor was bad.  I bought a new capacitor and put it in, same thing, lights but no fan. I'm getting power to the fan switch but the fan will not come on.

I'm thinking the fan motor may have crapped out. Totally stumped.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Are you sure the blue and black wires are hooked up to the power?  Make sure the rotation switch isn't stuck in the middle.

Comment: "I'm getting power to the fan switch but the fan will not come on." Use your multimeter to check for voltage on the output side of your fan switch when the switch is closed (on). If you have power there then you know the problem is in the fan motor. Also make sure that all of your connections are reliable and there is continuity through each wire.

Comment: The fan was working when you replaced the switch so it is probably mis wired or possibly while rewiring you could have knocked the neutral loose.